# SQL Server: How to limit CTE recursion to rows just recursivly added?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

### Simpler Example

Let's try a simpler example, so people can wrap their heads around the concepts, and have a practical example that you can copy&paste into SQL Query Analizer:

Imagine a **Nodes** table, with a heirarchy:

```
A
 - B
    - C
```

We can start testing in Query Analizer:

```
CREATE TABLE ##Nodes
(
 NodeID varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 ParentNodeID varchar(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, ParentNodeID) VALUES ('A', null)
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, ParentNodeID) VALUES ('B', 'A')
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, ParentNodeID) VALUES ('C', 'B')
```

**Desired output:**

```
ParentNodeID    NodeID    GenerationsRemoved
============    ======    ==================
NULL            A         1
NULL            B         2
NULL            C         3
A               B         1
A               C         2
B               C         1
```

Now the suggested CTE expression, with it's incorrect output:

```
WITH NodeChildren AS
(
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM ##Nodes
   WHERE ParentNodeID IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   --recursive execution
   SELECT P.ParentNodeID, N.NodeID, P.GenerationsRemoved + 1
   FROM NodeChildren AS P
      INNER JOIN ##Nodes AS N
      ON P.NodeID = N.ParentNodeID
)
SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, GenerationsRemoved
FROM NodeChildren
```

**Actual output**:

```
ParentNodeID    NodeID    GenerationsRemoved
============    ======    ==================
NULL            A         1
NULL            B         2
NULL            C         3
```

**Note:** If SQL Server 2005† CTE cannot do what i was doing before in 2000‡, that's fine, and that's the answer. And whoever gives "it's not possible" as the answer will win the bounty. But i will wait a few days to make sure everyone concur's that it's not possible before i irrecovably give 250 reputation for a non-solution to my problem.

**Nitpickers Corner**

†not 2008

‡without resorting to a UDF*, which is the solution already have

*unless you can see a way to improve the performance of the UDF in the original question

---

### Original Question

i have a table of Nodes, each with a parent that points to another Node (or to null).

For illustration:

```
1 My Computer
    2 Drive C
         4 Users
         5 Program Files
         7 Windows
             8 System32
    3 Drive D
         6 mp3
```

i want a table that returns all the parent-child relationships, and the number of generations between them

For for all direct parent relationships:

```
ParentNodeID  ChildNodeID  GenerationsRemoved
============  ===========  ===================
(null)        1            1
1             2            1
2             4            1
2             5            1
2             7            1
1             3            1
3             6            1
7             8            1
```

But then there's the grandparent relationships:

```
ParentNodeID  ChildNodeID  GenerationsRemoved
============  ===========  ===================
(null)        2            2
(null)        3            2
1             4            2
1             5            2
1             7            2
1             6            2
2             8            2
```

And the there's the great-grand-grandparent relationships:

```
ParentNodeID  ChildNodeID  GenerationsRemoved
============  ===========  ===================
(null)        4            3
(null)        5            3
(null)        7            3
(null)        6            3
1             8            3
```

So i can figure out the basic CTE initialization:

```
WITH (NodeChildren) AS
{
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID AS ChildNodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM Nodes
}
```

The problem now is the recursive part. The obvious answer, of course, doesn't work:

```
WITH (NodeChildren) AS
{
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, ChildNodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM Nodes

   UNION ALL

   --recursive execution
   SELECT parents.ParentNodeID, children.NodeID, parents.Generations+1
   FROM NodeChildren parents
    INNER JOIN NodeParents children
    ON parents.NodeID = children.ParentNodeID
} 

Msg 253, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Recursive member of a common table expression 'NodeChildren' has multiple recursive references.
```

All the information needed to generate the entire recursive list is present in the inital CTE table. But if that's not allowed i'll try:

```
WITH (NodeChildren) AS
{
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM Nodes

   UNION ALL

   --recursive execution
   SELECT parents.ParentNodeID, Nodes.NodeID, parents.Generations+1
   FROM NodeChildren parents
    INNER JOIN Nodes
    ON parents.NodeID = nodes.ParentNodeID
}
```

But that fails because it's not only joining on the recursive elements, but keeps recursivly adding the same rows over and over:

```
Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

In SQL Server 2000 i simulated a CTE by using a User Defined Function (UDF):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_NodeChildren] ()
RETURNS @Result TABLE (
    ParentNodeID int NULL,
    ChildNodeID int NULL,
    Generations int NOT NULL) 
AS  
/*This UDF returns all "ParentNode" - "Child Node" combinations
    ...even multiple levels separated
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Generations int
    SET @Generations = 1

    --Insert into the Return table all "Self" entries
    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, @Generations
    FROM Nodes
    WHILE @@rowcount > 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @Generations = @Generations + 1
        --Add to the Children table: 
        --  children of all nodes just added 
        -- (i.e. Where @Result.Generation = CurrentGeneration-1)
        INSERT @Result
        SELECT CurrentParents.ParentNodeID, Nodes.NodeID, @Generations
        FROM Nodes
            INNER JOIN @Result CurrentParents
            ON Nodes.ParentNodeID = CurrentParents.ChildNodeID
        WHERE CurrentParents.Generations = @Generations - 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

And the magic to keep it from blowing up was the limiting where clause:
    WHERE CurrentParents.Generations - @Generations-1

How do you prevent a recursive CTE from recursing forever?

Comment: Quite honestly - I do not think you can do this in a simple, one-step process. What you're trying to achieve is not "normal" hierarchical display from level to level, but a mix between several levels. This can't be handled by CTE or other methods....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH Nodes AS
(
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM ##Nodes

   UNION ALL

   ----recursive execution
   SELECT P.ParentNodeID, N.NodeID, P.GenerationsRemoved + 1
   FROM Nodes AS P
      INNER JOIN ##Nodes AS N
      ON P.NodeID = N.ParentNodeID
   WHERE P.GenerationsRemoved <= 10

)
SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, GenerationsRemoved
FROM Nodes
ORDER BY ParentNodeID, NodeID, GenerationsRemoved
```

Basically removing the "only show me absolute parents" from the initialization query; That way it generates the results starting from each of them and decending from there.  I also added in the "WHERE P.GenerationsRemoved <= 10" as an infinite recursion catch(replace 10 with any number up to 100 to fit your needs).  Then add the sort so it looks like the results you wanted.

Comment: Brilliant solution! If you still get the max recursion error with this it's because you have cyclic references in your hierarchy.

Comment: You can limit recursions using OPTION (MAXRECURSION nn) correctly. This is not a correct solution

Comment: OPTION(MAXRECURSION nn) causes the statement to fail; My goal with including the WHERE clause was to guarantee a return (obviously there will be times that a failure is better).

Comment: This solution works for me where MAXRECURSION will not. I have a special situation with legacy data where recursing too far can often find self referencing data. This allows me to only descend n deep where if you set MAXRECURSION to say, 5, it will throw the error on 5. This solution returns the first 5 regardless if there would have been an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Aside: do you have SQL Server 2008? This might be suited to the [`hierarchyid` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677212.aspx).

Comment: No, don't have 2008. And in 2003 when i originally need the problem solved, people said to wait for 2005.

Comment: Additionally, i can't get ahold of 2008, intall it, port the database to 2008, redesign the entire system, get the customer to buy, install and configured 2008 - all in the next few hours.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intentions you can get you result by doing something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartID INT;
SET @StartID = 1;
WITH CTE (ChildNodeID, ParentNodeID, [Level]) AS
(
  SELECT  t1.ChildNodeID, 
          t1.ParentNodeID, 
          0
  FROM tblNodes AS t1
  WHERE ChildNodeID = @StartID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  t1.ChildNodeID, 
          t1.ParentNodeID, 
          t2.[Level]+1
  FROM tblNodes AS t1
    INNER JOIN CTE AS t2 ON t1.ParentNodeID = t2.ChildNodeID    
)
SELECT t1.ChildNodeID, t2.ChildNodeID, t1.[Level]- t2.[Level] AS GenerationsDiff
FROM CTE AS t1
  CROSS APPLY CTE t2
```

This will return the generation difference between all nodes, you can modify it for you exact needs.

Comment: That doesn't work because it only starts from a specific node - i need all nodes. Then all those nodes children. Then all those node's children. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your answer is not quite that obvious :-)

```
WITH (NodeChildren) AS
{
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, ChildNodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM Nodes
```

This part is called the "anchor" part of the recursive CTE - but it should really only select one or a select few rows from your table - this selects everything!

I guess what you're missing here is simply a suitable WHERE clause:

```
WITH (NodeChildren) AS
{
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, ChildNodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM Nodes
   **WHERE ParentNodeID IS NULL**
```

However, I am afraid your requirement to have not just the "straight" hierarchy, but also the grandparent-child rows, might not be that easy to satisfy.... normally recursive CTE will only ever show one level and its direct subordinates (and that down the hierarchy, of course) - it doesn't usually skip one, two or even more levels.

Hope this helps a bit.

Marc

Comment: i can't limit it to rows with no parent, because then it limits to rows with no parent. i need to include rows with a parent also.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Sql Server default recursion limit (100).  If you try your example at the top with the anchor restriction removed (also added Order By):

```
WITH NodeChildren AS
(
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM Nodes

   UNION ALL

   --recursive execution
   SELECT P.ParentNodeID, N.NodeID, P.GenerationsRemoved + 1
   FROM NodeChildren AS P
      inner JOIN Nodes AS N
      ON P.NodeID = N.ParentNodeID
)
SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, GenerationsRemoved
FROM NodeChildren
ORDER BY ParentNodeID ASC
```

This produces the desired results. The problem you aare facing is with a larger number of rows you will recirse over 100 times which is a default limit.  This can be changed by adding `option (max recursion x)` after your query, where x is a number between 1 and 32767.  x can also be set to 0 which sets no limit however could very quickly have a very detrimental impact on your server performance.  Clearly as the number of rows in Nodes increases, the number of recursions will can rise very quickly and I would avoid this approach unless there was a known upper limit on the rows in the table.  For completeness, the final query should look like:

```
 WITH NodeChildren AS
    (
       --initialization
       SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
       FROM Nodes

       UNION ALL

       --recursive execution
       SELECT P.ParentNodeID, N.NodeID, P.GenerationsRemoved + 1
       FROM NodeChildren AS P
          inner JOIN Nodes AS N
          ON P.NodeID = N.ParentNodeID
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM NodeChildren
    ORDER BY ParentNodeID
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Where 32767 could be adjusted downwards to fit your scenario

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried constructing a path in the CTE and using it to identify ancestors?

You can then subtract the descendant node depth from the ancestor node depth to calculate the GenerationsRemoved column, like so...

```
DECLARE @Nodes TABLE
(
    NodeId varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ParentNodeId varchar(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Nodes (NodeId, ParentNodeId) VALUES ('A', NULL)
INSERT INTO @Nodes (NodeId, ParentNodeId) VALUES ('B', 'A')
INSERT INTO @Nodes (NodeId, ParentNodeId) VALUES ('C', 'B')

DECLARE @Hierarchy TABLE
(
    NodeId varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ParentNodeId varchar(50) NULL,
    Depth int NOT NULL,
    [Path] varchar(2000) NOT NULL
)

WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    --initialization
    SELECT NodeId, ParentNodeId, 0 AS Depth, CONVERT(varchar(2000), NodeId) AS [Path]
    FROM @Nodes
    WHERE ParentNodeId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    --recursive execution
    SELECT n.NodeId, n.ParentNodeId, p.Depth + 1, CONVERT(varchar(2000), p.[Path] + '/' + n.NodeId)
    FROM Hierarchy AS p
    INNER JOIN @Nodes AS n
    ON p.NodeId = n.ParentNodeId
)
INSERT INTO @Hierarchy
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy

SELECT parent.NodeId AS AncestorNodeId, child.NodeId AS DescendantNodeId, child.Depth - parent.Depth AS GenerationsRemoved
FROM @Hierarchy AS parent
INNER JOIN @Hierarchy AS child
ON child.[Path] LIKE parent.[Path] + '/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This breaks the recursion limit imposed on Chris Shaffer's answer.

I create a table with a cycle:

```
CREATE TABLE ##Nodes
(
   NodeID varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   ParentNodeID varchar(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, ParentNodeID) VALUES ('A', 'C');
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, ParentNodeID) VALUES ('B', 'A');
INSERT INTO ##Nodes (NodeID, ParentNodeID) VALUES ('C', 'B');
```

In cases where there is a potential cycle (i.e. ParentNodeId IS NOT NULL), the generation removed is started at 2. We can then identity cycles by checking (P.ParentNodeID == N.NodeID), which we simply don't add it. Afterwards, we append the omitted generation remove = 1.

```
WITH ParentNodes AS
(
   --initialization
   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM ##Nodes
   WHERE ParentNodeID IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT P.ParentNodeID, N.NodeID, 2 AS GenerationsRemoved
   FROM ##Nodes N
   JOIN ##Nodes P ON N.ParentNodeID=P.NodeID
   WHERE P.ParentNodeID IS NOT NULL

   UNION ALL

   ----recursive execution
   SELECT P.ParentNodeID, N.NodeID, P.GenerationsRemoved + 1
   FROM ParentNodes AS P
     INNER JOIN ##Nodes AS N
     ON P.NodeID = N.ParentNodeID
   WHERE P.ParentNodeID IS NULL OR P.ParentNodeID <> N.NodeID

),
Nodes AS (
   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved 
   FROM ##Nodes 
   WHERE ParentNodeID IS NOT NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, GenerationsRemoved FROM ParentNodes
)
SELECT ParentNodeID, NodeID, GenerationsRemoved
FROM Nodes
ORDER BY ParentNodeID, NodeID, GenerationsRemoved
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(
    select a=65, L=1
    union all
    select a+1, L=L+1
    from cte
    where L<=100
)
select 
IsRecursion=Case When L>1 then 'Recursion' else 'Not Recursion' end,
AsciiValue=a,
AsciiCharacter=char(a)
from cte
```

1. Create a column containing the current level.
2. Check if the level is >1

My example here shows a recursive CTE that stops recursion after 100 levels (the max).  As a bonus, it displays a bunch of ASCII characters and the corresponding numeric value.