# How to work around the "Recursive CTE member can refer itself only in FROM clause" requirement?

Tags: firebird, common-table-expression

I'm trying to run a graph search to find all nodes accessible from a starting point, like so:

```
with recursive
  nodes_traversed as (
    select START_NODE ID
    from START_POSITION

    union all
    select ed.DST_NODE
    from EDGES ed
    join nodes_traversed NT
      on (NT.ID = ed.START_NODE)
      and (ed.DST_NODE not in (select ID from nodes_traversed))
  )
select distinct * from nodes_traversed
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run that, I get an error:

> Recursive CTE member (nodes_traversed) can refer itself only in FROM clause.

That "not in select" clause is important to the recursive expression, though, as it provides the ending point.  (Without it, you get infinite recursion.)  Using generation counting, like in [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634971/sql-server-how-to-limit-cte-recursion-to-rows-just-recursivly-added), would not help, since this is a highly cyclic graph.

Is there any way to work around this without having to create a stored proc that does it iteratively?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution that use global temporary table, I have limited recursion by level and nodes from temporary table. 
I am not sure how it will work on large set of data.

```
create procedure get_nodes (
    START_NODE integer)
returns (
    NODE_ID integer)
as
declare variable C1 integer;
declare variable C2 integer;
begin

    /**
    create global temporary table id_list(
        id integer
    );
    create index id_list_idx1 ON id_list (id);
    */
    delete from id_list;


    while ( 1 = 1 ) do
    begin
        select count(distinct id) from id_list into :c1;

        insert into id_list
        select id from
            (
                with recursive nodes_traversed as (
                select :START_NODE AS ID , 0 as Lv
                from  RDB$DATABASE

                union all
                select ed.DST_NODE , Lv+1
                from  edges ed

                join nodes_traversed NT
                  on
                  (NT.ID = ed.START_NODE)
                  and nt.Lv < 5 -- Max recursion level
                  and nt.id not in (select id from id_list)
            )
        select distinct id from nodes_traversed);

        select count(distinct id) from id_list into :c2;
        if (c1 = c2) then break;
    end

    for select distinct  id from id_list into :node_id do
    begin
        suspend ;
    end
end
```