# How to restrict recursive CTE row count

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a function use to generate a record id, I want to use CTE to get batch of record id.
Now the recursive CTE like below

```
  with T as (
    select 
        dbo.Ufn_GetRecordId() AS recordId
    union all
    SELECT
        dbo.Ufn_GetRecordId() AS recordId
    FROM T

)select * from T
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0);
```

However, this query will not terminate. How restrict the count of CTE?(e.g. if I only need 3 rows in T)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like below. Idea taken from [SQL Server: How to limit CTE recursion to rows just recursivly added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634971/sql-server-how-to-limit-cte-recursion-to-rows-just-recursivly-added)

```
with T as (
    select 
        dbo.Ufn_GetRecordId() AS recordId, 1 as testnum
    union all
    SELECT
        dbo.Ufn_GetRecordId() AS recordId, testnum + 1
    FROM T
    WHERE testnum < 3

)select * from T
OPTION (MaxRecursion 0);
```

This will restrict to 3 returned rows.

Comment: `<= 3` will select four rows.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, that's a mistake. I mean `< 3`. edited and thanks for pointing.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for answering. I finally determine use a "WHILE" statement to archive this. After compared, "WHILE" seems make less logic read than "CTE"

Comment: @jojo, Yes, CTE would be better than loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly standard way of generating N rows with a recursive CTE.

```
WITH T 
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Dummy 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dummy + 1 
         FROM   T 
         WHERE  Dummy < 3) 
SELECT dbo.Ufn_GetRecordId() AS RecordId 
FROM   T;
```

If you need to generate more than 100 numbers then you'll need `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` (or some suitable value instead of `0`).